# Responsive image slider particular case

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive-design

I'm looking for an responsive image slider for a particular case.
This is what I would look to happen on desktop/tablet/mobile.

[image]

You can also swipe through the images on tablet/mobile.
It's important that the images don't need to have the same width. (height is always the same)

Does someone knows a js library for this?
I searched but most of the time you only have view of 1 image.

Comment: General plugin rarely fit particular case but it should not be so hard to code it from scratch, it'll just ask some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this?

http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php

It supports IE6+ and is very lightweight. You can easily make it responsive by wrapping it in a div with `overflow: hidden;` that varies in width as you require. Alternatively, you could have a go at rewriting it as you require (it's quite a lightweight script!)

Comment: Thx, but I don't think you can swipe through the images on tablet/mobile?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I'm afraid I don't know of any stock carousel that supports multiple widths and also touch swiping (and I know quite a few). I'm pretty sure you'll need to modify it to add swipe support. This project implements it quite well and the source code may be of use to you: https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe

Answer (score 2):

The lemmon slider works great with Touch Swipe. The instructions to add this are here:

https://github.com/lemmon/Lemmon-Slider/issues/5#issuecomment-25177163